# Constructor initialization: The assignment to variable length has no effect Warning

Tags: java

I am having a warning: The assignment to variable length has no effect and default values in the output.If I add this keyword warnings disappears. Why this is happening?
This is my code

```
  class Rectangle {
  int length;
  String breadth;

  Rectangle(int length,String breadth)
  {
  length  = length;
  breadth = breadth;
  }
}

class basic2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

  Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(20,"hi");

  System.out.println("Length of Rectangle : " + r1.length);
  System.out.println("Breadth of Rectangle : " + r1.breadth);

  }
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor parameters hide the class members since they have the same names. Therefore `length  = length;` assigns a variable onto itself, which is meaningless.

To fix it, use the `this` keyword to refer to the class members :

```
Rectangle(int length,String breadth)
{
  this.length  = length;
  this.breadth = breadth;
}
```

Comment: Thought the term ctor would only be used in C#/C++  =)

Comment: @MuratK.That's what happens when I try to type fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are refering to the parameter of the constructor. Use `this.length=length`